# constant int and pointers example

Tags: pointers, int, constants

```
int main() {
    const int i = 1;
    const int* p = &i;
    int j = 2;
    const int* q = &j;
    j = 3;
    printf("%d", *p + *q);
    return 0;
}
```

I have this code, and I try to understand how it compiles. p and q are pointers to constant integers but j isn't declared as constant. Moreover, j changes into 3.

How does it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On the 5th line, you're assigning the address of variable j to q. This do not enforce any constraint over *j*, just on pointer *q*. Through *q* the compiler won't allow you to change pointed value, however j remains writeable and the line `j = 3;` is legal.

See [What is the difference between const int*, const int * const, and int const *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const/1143272#1143272)